# How to access other database within orchard

Tags: sql, database-connection, orchardcms

I am trying to access an external database to display data in an orchard module my firs attempt I got the following error.

An unhandled exception has occurred and the request was terminated. Please refresh the page. If the error persists, go back

> The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string.
>
> System.Data.ProviderIncompatibleException: The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: MSDTC on server 'ML-52\SQLEXPRESS' is unavailable.

I was just taking a stab in the dark if anyone has done this or has a simple module that connects to an external DB please share. It will be much appriciated

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Surround your data access with

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress)) {
```